# databricks - mounted S3 - how to get file metadata like last modified date (Python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have mounted a s3 bucket in my databricks and I can see the list of files and i can read the files as well using python

```
ACCESS_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX"
SECRET_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
ENCODED_SECRET_KEY = SECRET_KEY.replace("/", "%2F")
AWS_BUCKET_NAME = "testbucket"
MOUNT_NAME = "awsmount1"

dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s:%s@%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, ENCODED_SECRET_KEY, AWS_BUCKET_NAME), "/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME)
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/%s/data" % MOUNT_NAME))
```

I want to find out the last modified date of the file i am reading, I couldn't find much but the java option [Databricks read Azure blob last modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584561/databricks-read-azure-blob-last-modified-date) for azure blob, is there a python native option in databricks to read the file metadata.

Comment: I think the AWS SDK may be the best bet with the last modified date. I couldn't find anything on the CLI or REST API that can help, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you need the last modified date for mounted file in Azure data bricks using python native sdk.

Here is the sample code to get the metadata information from Azure blob:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='accoutName', account_key='accountKey')
container_name ='containerName'
block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
for blob in generator:
    lastModified= BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name).properties.last_modified
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
    print(lastModified)
```

you can get more details on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.blobproperties?view=azure-python).

If you are looking fro S3 then i would suggest you to use Boto.oto3 returns a datetime object for LastModified when you use the the (S3) Object python object:

```
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.last_modified
```

To compare LastModified to today's date (Python3):

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')

objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket='my_bucket')

for o in objects["Contents"]:
    if o["LastModified"] == today:
        print(o["Key"])
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679344/how-can-i-get-last-modified-datetime-of-s3-objects-with-boto/22831019#22831019)

Hope it helps.